# WebFocus OR Microstrategy

Tags: microstrategy, webfocus

i am working as reports developer using Cognos BI and i want to learn any one of below BI tools.

1. Microstrategy
2. WebFocus

Can any one suggest the best tool from above  to learn in career perspective.

Thanks,

Phani

Answer (score 4):

Disclaimer, I'm a former MicroStrategy employee and I never worked on WebFocus.

My suggestion is to go with MicroStrategy, first of all your knowledge of BI and SQL will came very handy to you to understand how the MicroStrategy SQL engine works and how the objects you create in MicroStrategy will be transformed on the database side.

So, if you have your back(-end) covered you can focus on the other key features of MicroStrategy: in memory cubes, possibility to connect to MDX sources or webservices, advanced analytics and above all the mobile part.

If you are more interested in the nerdy stuff (maybe it's not your case, but I came to BI from the SQL side) the focus on the Mobile and Data Visualization (MicroStrategy Visual Insight) can be a bit appalling, but I believe that to have an exposure to the front-end components is important to see the big picture.

Anyway career wise MicroStrategy looks to me a more wise choice than WebFocus, but as I said at beginnin my perception can be biased

Answer (score 0):

Offcourse Microstrategy.

Its an awesome tool provides the vast ability to analyze huge amounts of data.
Microstrategy provides flexibility to the users, good scalability, nice user interface & impressive iPad capabilities.

And career is always green compared to WebFocous.

My vote goes for Microstrategy!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've always tried to make decisions like this, by focusing on what will be best for my users, rather than what would be best for me.

To support this type of focus with the question at hand, take a look at things like strength/longevity of vendor, scope of product offerings, simplicity of implementation/maintenance, number of back-end databases/appliances supported, number of/type of report/graph formats, scalability,...

Good luck with your decision!